# 3D modelling Wired Designs

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I came across this 3d printed item on shapeways, I was wondering how to model this wired design on Blender 2.69. I am fairly new in modelling on blender. Kindly give me one or two pointers.
[image: Wired Design]

[image: Wired]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by modelling the wire shape, then using a Skin modifier to turn the edges into solid geometry that could be printed. I've seen the Skin modifier used to make basic figures based on a skeleton, and it works on the default cube, but when I just tried it on a Monkey, blender crashed for me, so make sure you save your work before you attempt to use the modifier!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the new *[Wireframe modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Wireframe)* to do this. It will convert edges into solid geometry:

[image]

[image]

Or you can use the old *[Wireframe](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/BMesh#Wireframe_Tool)* tool:

1. Select your mesh and enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>*> Wireframe*.

Comment: add edgesplit modifier and move it at the top to give it better look (it will remove those rounded inner sides and give a proper wireframe look.

Comment: @dukejib You can do that by enabling *Crease Edges* in the modifier and setting the crease weight to `1`. (In the screenshot it is `.5`, I rather liked the effect..). I tried the edge split modifier after reading your comment, but I did not get the expected result.

Comment: yeah. you are right. i forgot to mention crease,